# Android bitmap compress webp to jpg not change mime type

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, jpeg, webp

when I use compress(CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream) function to compress webp to jpg, it's suffix change to .jpg.

But it's mimeType doesn't change, still "image/webp".

So there is a problem which phone dosen't support webp will not preview it.
Could anyone give me the answer?

```
webpBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 45, fos)

//get mime type from bitmap file
val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath, options)
return options.outMimeType

// it return "image/webp" not "image/jpg"
```

the question is why **bitmap.compress** will not change file mime type

Comment: What is a webp? Where do you see that suffix? Where do you see thar mime type?

Comment: Bitmaps have no suffix or mimetype so it is unclear where you see changes.